# closing a boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket with pending connect

Tags: boost, boost-asio

According to the boost asio documentation, if I call close on a socket that has an asynchronous connect operation pending, the handler will be called "immediately" with an error code.  From the documentation:

> This function is used to close the socket. Any asynchronous send, receive or connect operations will be cancelled immediately, and will complete with the boost::asio::error::operation_aborted error.

But the handler is not actually called immediately/synchronously, it is called asynchronously when control returns to the io_service.  Is it possible that my connect handler still gets called **without** an error code *after* I call close, if the connect actually succeeded and my handler callback has already been posted to the io_service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation states that the outstanding operations will be *canceled* immediately, not that they will be *called* immediately.

It is possible that the connect operation has already completed, and the handler is queued in the `io_service` for deferred invocation with its `error_code` as `boost::system::errc::success`.  It may be worth consider checking if the socket [`is_open()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/is_open.html) in the completion handler, as done in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14592506/1053968) answer.  For more details on this behavior, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14116082/1053968) answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Would you then agree the documentation is not strictly correct in this regard?  The claim that "Any asynchronous send, receive or connect operations will be cancelled immediately, and will complete with the boost::asio::error::operation_aborted error.", is not necessarily true.

Comment: The documentation is strictly correct.  The lifespan of an asynchronous operation ends when it has completed; it is not dictated by the posting or invocation of the completion handler.  When `cancel()` is invoked, all asynchronous operations will be canceled, and their handlers will be set for deferred invocation with *error* set to `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted error`.

Answer (score 1):

The operations will be cancelled immediately, but the handler doesn't get called synchronously. If a "normal" completion handler is already in the queue when you call `close()`, it definitely will be invoked, and you won't get "operation_aborted".

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I agree, having read it more carefully the wording is not unclear.